# Google Docs - Convert date into day of the year

Tags: spreadsheet, google-docs

Task is pretty simple and I know I could calculate it myself but can't believe there is no dedicated function for it in GDocs already.

Today is 2019-11-28 it's 332 day of the year.

How to get that integer in google docs spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to retrieve the days between 2 days using Google Spreadsheet.

If my understanding is correct, how about using `DAYS()` of the built-in function?

#### Sample formula:

```
=DAYS("2019/11/28", "2019/01/01")
```

- In this case, when above formula is put to a cell on the Google Spreadsheet, 331 is returned. In your question, If you want to retrieve the result of 332, you think of `=DAYS("2019/11/28", "2018/12/31")`?

#### Reference:

- [DAYS function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9061296)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Hi, it's exactly what I was looking for and now I am embarrassed that this thought did not cross my mind. :-D

Comment: @Drachenfels Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.